# Equivalent while loop block for a for loop block

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am a novice trying to learn python from *Automate The Boring Stuff with Python* by Al Sweigart and I came across his block of code to answer a math problem: "What is the sum of all the numbers from 0 to 100?" Apparently, this was a question Gauss got when his teacher wanted to keep him busy.

Sweigart used a `for` loop and `range()` function to get the answer:

```
total = 0
for num in range(101):
    total=total+num
print(total)
```

A page later he states that "you can actually use a while loop to do the same thing as a for loop; for loops are more concise."

**How would this statement be rendered in a while loop?**

I tried replacing the `for` with `while` but got an error: "name 'num' is not defined." I also tried to set up a summation math equation using another block of code from another forum, but completely got lost.

```
print('Gauss was presented with a math problem: add up all the numbers from 0 to 100. What was the total?')
a=[1,2,3,4,5,...,100]
i=0
while i< len(a)-1:
    result=(a[i]+a[i+1])/2
    print(result)
    i +=1
```

Then, I tried to setup `i` in an equation that would loop until each number was added, but got stuck.

```
print('Gauss was presented with a math problem: add up all the numbers from 0 to 100. What was the total?')
i=0
while i<101:
    i=i+1
    a=i
```

Would the while statement be too complex to warrant the effort?

Comment: In the code where you claim it says "name 'num' is not defined", there is no "num", so you must be referring to some different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop is more concise. Notice how we need a "counter" variable , in this case `i` with the while loop. That's not to say we don't need them in a `for` loop, however they're integrated nicely into the syntax to make for cleaner code.

```
i = 0
total = 0
while i < 101:
    total += i
    i += 1
print(total)
```

Python's for loop syntax is also a foreach equivalent:

```
for eachItem in list:
# Do something
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the type of code break down I was looking for. I kept stumbling on figuring out how to get the equations to feed into each other. Now I see that you need a second variable to avoid i being turned to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your last example comes close.

A `for` loop of this form:

```
for x in range(N):
    # ...
```

can be replaced by a `while` loop like this:

```
x = 0
while x < N:
    # ...
    x += 1  # equivalent to x = x + 1
```

Just make sure you leave the rest of the code unchanged!